# Mapping Series chunks with map-fn

Tags: common-lisp, series

I am using Common Lisp Series package ( https://series.sourceforge.net/ ) to work on Advent Of Code.

```
(series::defun find-14-character-marker (stream)
  (declare (optimizable-series-function))
  (declare (off-line-port stream))
  (->> (mapping (((a b c d e f g h i j k l m n) (chunk 14 1 stream)))
        (char/= a b c d e f g h i j k l m n))
       (until-if #'identity)
       (collect-length)))
```

Is it possible to map chunks using `map-fn` function instead of `mapping`?
I could do something like this:

```
(lambda (&rest xs)
  (apply #'char/= xs))
```

without having to type all 14 parameters.  I tried using `map-fn` but my lambda function was invoked with only one parameter.

Comment: So far I don't think it is possible, the only way I see to abstract this is to generate the 14 symbols from a macro.

Answer (score 0):

`chunk` returns its series as multiple values, while `map-fn` requires each of its argument series as individual arguments. Therefore, `(multiple-value-call #'map-fn 'boolean #'char= (chunk 14 1 stream))` is the form you're looking for, as it will pass each of the multiple series returned by `chunk` as an argument to `map-fn`. (the `#'char=` is used in place of the lambda given in the question, as it is equivalent).

By default, when a form which evaluates to multiple values is used as an argument to a function, all values but the first are discarded, which is probably why your original attempt to use `map-fn` failed. `multiple-value-call` instead passes each of the multiple values of the form as individual arguments, which is what you want here.

Comment: It's true but SERIES has a custom semantics and does warn about the use of multiple-value-call